# Add TODO list (rake notes) output to source control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rake, rake-task, todo

I want my TODO list which I get as output of 'rake notes' to be under source control (Git).
Is there a way I can configure 'rake notes' to spit out out a text file which can be under source control?

Answer (score 0):

Not completely understanding your question's direction, so I'll just go from the beginning. :)

Create a rake file :)

The most common is under Rails.root / lib, but it's preferable (depending on Elitests or purists) to put it under `lib/tasks/output_notes.rake` (yes, .rake, not .rb)

Rake scripts have namespaces. "db" is a namespace for running "rake db:migrate" for example. You can see some examples here: https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/tasks

Your script might look something like this.

```
namespace :vasa do 
  desc "Output notes"
  task :output_notes do 
    output_file_name = "#{DateTime.now.to_i}_notes.txt"
    File.open(output_file_name, 'w') { |file| file.write(Note.dump_all) }
  end
end
```

You can then run `rake vasa:output_notes`. Want to add the file to your repo automagically?

```
# after File.open ...
 `
 git add #{output_file_name}
 git commit -m "added notes"
 `
```

The backticks will run it as a system command.

Comment: How do I get the output of 'rake notes:todo' in the output_file?

Comment: You mean if it was worked or not? You could do `File.exists?(output_file_name)` or something along those lines. You could also set a variable to `File.open`